# How to add video to nivo slider?

Tags: jquery, video, embed, nivo-slider

I have set up nivo slider in a Homepage. But now, I need to show a video inside that slider, but I have found that **nivo slider** goes bananas when I add a video:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="URL" width="470" height="344" title="#caption1">
                            <param name="movie" value="URL"></param>
                            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                            <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
                            <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="URL" width="470" height="344"></embed>
                        </object>
```

Has anyone made a change to **nivo core** to allow adding video feature or deal with similar issues?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use [Anything Slider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) instead.

From Official Site:

> Features:
>
> Panels are HTML Content (can be anything).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nivo Gallery](http://nivogallery.dev7studios.com/) instead

Answer (score 0):

From the Support Staff:

> Unfortunately, the slider is only suitable for images at the moment.

http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/general-discussion/246-using-nivo-slider-for-youtube-videos#comment_12795752

Maybe you have luck using an animated gif.

Comment: jaajj a gif, thank you. There is no way to change core and add video feature? God, I will have to change hole structure...

Comment: @LeandroCusack of course you could add this functionality to Nivo Slider but that's way to complex to discuss here!

Comment: I like complex things, I wonder if you could "give me a hand", I am learning core to detect when it recognize only images

Comment: I think that modifying some methods it could be done, like "createSlice" for example

Comment: @LeandroCusack, were you successful in modifying Nivo Slider to have video along with image(s)?

Comment: @Vikram sorry, I could not see this before. I finally use "BX SLIDER".

Answer (score 0):

use [BxSlider](http://bxslider.com/examples/video) its for both image and Vedio